# The cofree coalgebra using adjoint functor theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, adjoint-functors, coalgebras

Let $k$ be a commutative ring. There is a forgetful functor
$$U : \mathsf{Coalg}_k \to \mathsf{Mod}_k$$
from $k$-[coalgebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coalgebra) to $k$-modules. This has a right adjoint, called the [cofree coalgebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cofree+coalgebra) on a $k$-module (for instance, see section 1.6 in the book "[Hopf algebras](https://books.google.de/books/about/Hopf_Algebra.html?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&redir_esc=y)" by Dascalescu, Nastasescu, Raianu).

**Question 1.** In Michael Barr's paper "[Coalgebras over a commutative ring](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/coalgs.pdf)", it is shown that $U$ has a right adjoint using the *[special adjoint functor theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem)*. In order to apply this, $\mathsf{Coalg}_k$ should have a small genenerating set. Why does Barr say nothing about this? And how to prove that $\mathsf{Coalg}_k$ has a small generating set? If $k$ is a field (more generally, when $k$ is absolutely flat), this follows from the fundamental theorem on coalgebras.

**Question 2.** Can we prove the existence of the cofree coalgebra using the *[general adjoint functor theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem)*? For this, we would have to check that for every $k$-module $M$ the category $U \downarrow M$ has a weakly terminal set of objects. But I could not find it so far.

**Question 3.** (Edit: moved to [math.SE/1631890](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631890))

**Question 4.** More generally, let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a cocomplete monoidal category (i.e. $\mathcal{C}$ is cocomplete and $\otimes$ is cocontinuous in each variable). Under what conditions does the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Coalg}(\mathcal{C},\otimes) \to \mathcal{C}$ have a right adjoint?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to split up these *four* questions into at least 2-3 questions... Especially now that (as far as I understand, sorry if I understood incorrectly) there is an answer that only addresses two of the four questions. If necessary you can link the questions to one another. Question 3 in particular seems quite independent from the others.

Comment: I will ask Q3 separately.

Comment: In Q2, shouldn't you be looking for a weakly _terminal_ set of objects?

Comment: I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{C}$ is an accessible category and $\otimes$ is an accessible functor, then $\mathbf{Coalg} (\mathcal{C})$ is accessible. This is a special case of the theorem on 2-limits of accessible categories; after all, $\mathbf{Coalg} (\mathcal{C})$ can be constructed using comma categories, products, iso-inserters, and equifiers. (This is the same argument used to show that the category of (co)algebras for an accessible (co)monad is accessible.) This yields the desired generating set.

In particular, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a locally presentable monoidal closed category, then $\mathbf{Coalg} (\mathcal{C})$ is also locally presentable and the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Coalg} (\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ has a right adjoint.

Comment: Thank you; this answers 1 and 4 quite abstractly. Is it possible to "write down" a generating set?

Comment: I suppose it's possible in principle. If you know that $\mathbf{Coalg} (\mathcal{C})$ is $\kappa$-accessible then the $\kappa$-presentable objects form a dense subcategory. The problem is that, in the standard textbooks, no estimate of $\kappa$ is given – you have to chase through the proofs carefully. However, you might have better luck looking at the 1977 preprint of Ulmer (check your email).